# .NET Core 3.1 - dotnet ef add migration error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

When I try to create a migration in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project, I get this error - I need help

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /Users/remzi/.dotnet/tools/.store/dotnet-ef/6.0.7/dotnet-ef/6.0.7/tools/net6.0/any/tools/netcoreapp2.0/any/ef.dll
Architecture: arm64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' (arm64)
.NET location: /usr/local/share/dotnet/

The following frameworks were found:
  6.0.7 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=arm64&rid=osx.12-arm64
```

Comment: It seems like your missing the Core 3.1 Runtime.

Comment: I downloaded the Core 3.1 Runtime from the link in the error, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Try to relaunch the visual studio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Took me a lifetime to find the solution to this. 3.1 won't work because there is no arm64 version despite what it expects. To get around this you can force it to use this latest by typing the following into the terminal

```
export DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD=LatestMajor
```

Comment: Took me a lifetime to find this post, but you made my day! Thank you!

Comment: can you please let me know where this line need to add in the project. Which file.

Comment: This is an environment variable which needs to be set before you run the dotnet command. In Powershell, do `$env:DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD="LatestMajor"`

Comment: Also, it is important to run whatever dotnet command in powershell if you are a Windows user. So, your steps will consist of next stages: 

1) Launch PowerShell. 2) $env:DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD="LatestMajor". 3)dotnet (your command)